# Why does the controller need access to the model in a web PHP MVC?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, web, model, controller

Why wouldn't MVC not work just fine if the controller would only have access to the view (diagram #2 in the image below) and the view would have access to the model?

On most sites (some topics on Stack Overflow included), I have read that it's should be like shown in the left diagram (diagram #1 in the image below).

I have added an image, just so that you can understand my question better (don't mind that this is a UML diagram, look at it just as an normal diagram).

[image]

NOTE: Of course there is an `dataMapper` to which one the model has access and an `init` and `frontController` above the `controller`, etc. But I didn't add them to the image just to keep it as simple as possible.

Comment: Because on the web that is hard to do with just php. Hence most PHP MVC projects just abuse MVC as a marketing term.

Comment: Which part would be hard to do? Could you be more specific please? I tested this approach (where the controller doesn't have access to the model), and i can't find a reason why it shouldn't be like that... Of course the test application is small... That's why i opened this question here.

Comment: You cannot have a persistent model layer for view(s) to observe. That's the case for web in general. This is the reason why we have other MVC-like, MVC-inspired and not-MVC-but-advertised-as (rails, laravel, asp.net mvc) patterns.

Comment: @tereško Could you explain this statement of yours: "You cannot have a persistent model layer for view(s) to observe." in more detail please?

Comment: I am really trying to not write a complete answer .. To begin with, check the article in wikipedia about MVC. In the classical MVC patter, the views observer the model and, when the model's state is altered, the view retrieves necessary data from model updates the UI accordingly. To better understand the challenges, you would have to start by understanding [the observer pattern](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/observer/php).

Comment: @tereško could you provide an example of something that could not be done if the controller would not have access to the model?

Comment: Why would you prevent controller from having access to the model layer structures?

Comment: If it's not needed, why should it be there (i'm trying to find out for what it's needed)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's about simply *displaying* data, then yes, the schematic should be that the controller invokes a view and the view gets data from the model to visualise its state.

However, oftentimes the controller triggers *change* in the model's state. E.g. a user asks to be logged in, a new entry is posted, an old entry is deleted, or any other kind of change that's triggered by incoming requests. The controller propagates those "write requests" to the appropriate model method and decides on what should be done further based on the outcome. The view is "read only", it's not its job to handle such things.

Comment: Why must the view be bad? Just curious. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: It's about distributing responsibilities correctly; that's all MVC is about really. The responsibility of the view is to *display*, regardless of context. There could be any number of different controller actions which trigger the same view as response; you don't want to tie any "write" logic to the view in this case.

Comment: At deceze this comment/argument satisfied my question. Just to round it up... The access to the model from the controller is needed because without it, the view would had to do non-display responsibilities. Thank you! Question closed.